# Is it possible to have conditional callback argument types? (e.g. if arg1: string then arg0: null)

Tags: typescript

I am trying to have some conditional type logic for a callback's parameter types.

Essentially the first argument is the value and the second is a possible error message.

```js
type CallbackWithoutError = (value: string, error: undefined) => void
type CallbackWithError = (value: undefined, error: string) => void

declare const foo: (cb: CallbackWithError | CallbackWithoutError) => void

// Assume CallbackWithError
foo((value, error) => {
   if (error) {
      // handle
      return
   }
   // Now CallbackWithoutError
   console.log(value)
})
```

Is it possible for TypeScript to assume the callback has the "with error" arguments first.

The if statement checking for the `error` value disqualifies "with error" so the "without error" type is used going forward

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you might want to try using discriminating tuple:

```
// Declare that the parameters can only be one of the two tuple types:
type Callback = (...p: [string, undefined] | [undefined, string]) => void

declare const foo: (cb: Callback) => void

foo((...p) => {
    if (p[1] !== undefined) {
        // handle
        return
    } else {
        console.log(p[0]) // TypeScript knows that it must be a string now.
    }
})
```

See this [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PTAEBEFMGMBsEMBOlQBcAW9VvSgDkvALaSqSIDOo08AdqAPa2wCeoARik1wGY4qoA7gzQBXPLAEs8kCgC4AUKmkoAwvFix28aAGtQAXlAAKAHTm8c0AG0KqRAEtaAcwA0oUbQAmkHk8heALqgAD42nj5+tAHudo4ugQCUhgB8oABuDA5eCgo+cEgo0Ex2oDwMDFbG0OxW6praeskGaZnZueUMxmYWzWkA3gqgw6AOfMZ41gCMwQCEBkYRvv5eyYMjG6AgoJjekkObw8ioooi0B8MAvqCQsBQo64fUJQySprAMzhPWAAxJW2AACoqADK0EceGwuloDEEVAwWFG2CIolKnFA8FAcSczlAMMEpguoEuCkuiSAA).